# Set path from DOCUMENT_ROOT in <file>

Tags: php, .htaccess

In parent directory i have htaccess

```
<files error.php>
    Header add X-HeaderName "Header Value"
</files>
```

Parent folder has a file called `error.php` and a child folder which also contains a file called `error.php`.

How to create a rule that will apply only to the file in the parent directory?

Comment: Have you tried to simply put .htaccess in this directory and just use `RewriteBase /` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your .htaccess file and the error.php that you want to reference are in the same directory. If so, you could try...

```
<files ./error.php>
  Header add X-HeaderName "Header Value"
</files>
```

To tell the htaccess to use the file in the current directory, which is represented by the ./

I have no means to test this now, but its worth a shot

Comment: Damned, too slow. Would've been my suggestion as well! +1 ;-)